# Rest Cypher query parameters - From .net to java

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to send cypher query with parameters from .net to neo4j server with  Rest method

i get this error :

Problem accessing /db/data/cypher. Reason:

```
    java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

#### Caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

`This is the Code : 
        DateTime startQueryTime = DateTime.Now;
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher");
        restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        restClient.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        JObject parameters1 = new JObject();
        parameters.Add("startName", "Alon");

        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(); ;
        restRequest.AddParameter("query", "START root=node:Node_Type(Type=\"Person\") where root.Person_Name = {startName} RETURN root limit 20");
        restRequest.AddParameter("params", parameters1);

        IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Post(restRequest);`

thanks in advance.

Alon

Answer (score 1):

The result of your query is of the form `Map<String,Object>` instead of `String`. The result map contains the node property names as keys and its values represented as objects.

Answer (score 0):

Examine your actual REST outgoing call and make sure the parameters map is not serialized to a String but a JSON Map structure.